# SinonJS stub getter defined with configurable false

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, auth0

I'm trying to stub [nodeJS auth0 lib](https://github.com/auth0/node-auth0) `ManagementClient.prototype.createUser` using `SinonJS`.

The problem is that `createUser` is a getter defined with `Object.defineProperty` using `configurable: false` hence using `sinon.replaceGetter()` or `sinon.stub(object, 'method').get(fn)` throws `Cannot redeclare property`. I opened [an issue](https://github.com/auth0/node-auth0/issues/299) about it on their Github's repo and someone told me that `sinon.stub(ManagementClient.prototype, 'createUser', fn)` was working but the problem is that this syntax is deprecated since `v3.0.0`. I tried using `sinon.stub(ManagementClient.prototype, 'createUser').callsFake(fn)` which is supposed to replace the old syntax but it doesn't work as the previous syntax seemed to. Here is a [runkit](https://runkit.com/nargonath/5baa196409324800125fd589) showing that in action.

My question is: is there a way for me to stub that getter even though it is declared as `configurable: false` or am I screwed? I can't seem to find a way.

I already asked them if they would consider updating their `Object.defineProperty` call to set `configurable: true` but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be possible to override the property defined with `configuration: false` so I ended up making my own wrapper around `Auth0` SDK and stubbed it instead of the SDK itself.

Here is an example:

If you have the SDK with a `foo()` method. You then create a new class:

```js
import Auth0 from 'auth0';

class Auth0Wrapper {
  foo() {
    return Auth0.foo();
  }
}
```

This class is really dumb it acts as a proxy to the original method. The point is just that now you can easily stub your class no matter how the underlying SDK was developed.

Comment: care to share what that wrapper looks like?